# Invalid twilio 4.0.1-1 package for Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, twilio, apt

From https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sip/quickstart (Linux instructions)

The latest twilio package (4.0.1-1) has a bad size in the repository:

```
apt install twilio
<snip>
Get:1 https://twilio-cli-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/apt  twilio 4.0.1-1 [38.0 MB]
Err:1 https://twilio-cli-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/apt  twilio 4.0.1-1
  File has unexpected size (37949880 != 37950428). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 52.216.77.100 443]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA512:09994d384d13b150e4fe239677abe31dec4e51177cfe407102c99759708556c4fa4008e6597f7c5333549b563e2bbb26ab505f7f9b2479ab35982be69db076a3
   - SHA256:6c1b505ecbddb309b1be6833b4c1a9b911450c8773ed00fff9ea2c259dfe6b8d
   - SHA1:5551dfd306d67a6a4603aa214e4a6b54eb8c65d2 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:8070205542f19eb9601e93eb5fab845b [weak]
   - Filesize:37950428 [weak]
<snip>
```

Installing the previous version (3.6.0-1) works well:

```
sudo apt-cache madison twilio
sudo apt install -y twilio=3.6.0-1
```

But then the upgrade to 4.0.1-1 fails (as per above).

Something got broken when the package was pushed to the S3 bucket. A few bytes seem missing or the signature was done for a different package.

Listing the published packages, I can see two different packages with the same version 4.0.1-1:

```
sudo apt-cache madison twilio 
    twilio |    4.0.1-1 | https://twilio-cli-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/apt  Packages
    twilio |    4.0.1-1 | https://twilio-cli-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/apt  Packages
    twilio |    3.6.0-1 | https://twilio-cli-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/apt  Packages
<snip>
```

It looks the latest push re-used the same version but should have been bumped.

I hope Twilio tech support sees these error reports.

Comment: Thank you for this report, I have forwarded it to the CLI team at Twilio. Since this is not a code issue that we can fix, it is normally better to raise this sort of thing with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) who can also pass it on and track updates. In this case I have alerted the team though.

Comment: The team just released a new version and this issue should be resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

After checking with the CLI team, there is two bits of advice.

First, you can try waiting for a bit then running `sudo apt-get update`, that might sort any caching issues.

To unblock you right now though, you can download the file directly from the [GitHub release executable](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-cli/releases/tag/4.0.1) and install manually.

We'll keep looking into why this happened though.

**Edit**

As of 25th August, this issue should be resolved and you can successfully `apt install twilio` again.